# How do you copy Maven dependencies (jar files) from one Java project to another Dynamic web project's WEB-INF/lib folder?

Tags: eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee, jar, dependency-management

I am trying to use a Java project called "Search" in my another Web project.  I exported the Search project as a jar and added to my Web project's WEB-INF/lib folder.  The problem is that the Search projects has many dependencies for Accumulo, Hadoop, Zookeeper etc.  So how can I copy these maven dependencies/jar files from the Search project to my Web apps' WEB-INF/lib folder so I can get everything working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using Maven, all you need to do is to add the "Search" project as a [dependency](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies) to your Web project. Maven will resolve any [transitive](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies) dependencies like Accumolo, Hadoop, Zookeper, etc, automatically for you.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply add the uses things like Accumulo, Hadoop etc. as usual dependencies in your project. So they will be packaged in your war project automatically.

Comment: This doesn't work for me and I don't have a war folder.  I had to manually add all the necessary jars into the WEB-INF/lib folder and the build path.

Comment: Hm. Do you have a Maven project which produces a war file? The Maven project will create the war file.

Comment: It is a Maven project but there is no war file anywhere.  I thought this was maybe because I chose the packaging method to be jar instead of war so I created a new project and and set the maven packaging to war this time and added all the dependencies to pom.xml but I still didn't see a war file generated.

Answer (score 1):

There may be other way, but my approach is.

1. In your project click maven dependencies to expand.
2. Select Jar Files you require and Copy(Cntrl+C)
3. Paste it in Notepad++ or in your Eclipse(Any type file)

[Now you will get something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82MLn.png)

4. Clear Download folder in your file system. Because you are downloading all jar files from Browser instead of Navigating to each folder in file system.
5. Just copy line by line in to your browser URL tab. It will be downloaded to the Downloads from where you can copy easily to the WEB-INF/lib folder.

Note: You can automate this process by

- Writing a Java code(java.io)
- Creating array of string or reading from a text file line by line
- creating array of file copying to a folder by iteration.

Hope it will helps.

[Downloaded by manual process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FwUf.png)