# Tell maven to use jars from lib folder

Tags: eclipse, maven

So for a Dynamic Web Project in eclipse, I already have any external libraries that I need under WebContent\WEB-INF\lib, but for some reason Maven doesn't think to include these libraries and only wants to use the ones from .m2/repository. These libs are already included with the project, there should be no reason that maven needs to go download its own version, so how do I make it use the existing ones?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you copy Maven dependencies (jar files) from one Java project to another Dynamic web project's WEB-INF/lib folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11250183/how-do-you-copy-maven-dependencies-jar-files-from-one-java-project-to-another)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### [Guide to installing 3rd party JARs](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html)

> Although rarely, but sometimes you will have 3rd party JARs that you
>   need to put in your local repository for use in your builds, since
>   they don't exist in any public repository like Maven Central. The JARs
>   must be placed in the local repository in the correct place in order
>   for it to be correctly picked up by Apache Maven. To make this easier,
>   and less error prone, we have provide a goal in the
>   maven-install-plugin which should make this relatively painless. To
>   install a JAR in the local repository use the following command:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> \
    -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>
```

#### If there's a pom-file as well, you can install it with the following command:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DpomFile=<path-to-pomfile>
```

> With version 2.5 of the maven-install-plugin it gets even better. If
>   the JAR was built by Apache Maven, it'll contain a pom.xml in a
>   subfolder of the META-INF directory, which will be read by default. In
>   that case, all you need to do is:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file>
```

*Delete the ones in `WEB-INF/lib` and do it the correct way. Anything is a localhack and will end in tears!*

Comment: I already have jars that are bundled with the project. There is no need to install them when they are right there in a folder. All maven needs to do is look there and use them.

Comment: if you think you know better than everyone else in the world that does it the way it should be done, then why are you wanting to use Maven if you don't want to learn how to use it correctly?

Comment: Well if they aren't in lib then eclipse breaks then you have to go hunt down which folder the jar is in out of the hundreds in m2

Comment: no it doesn't if you import the project by selecting the `pom.xml` the way you are supposed to, it then uses the `classpath` that Maven generates. again, why are you using Eclipse if you don't want to understand how to use it correctly?

Comment: ok I wasn't aware maven could actually set up the classpaths for you